# Duplicate numbers reading a text file in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python script which I'm trying to use to print duplicate numbers in the `Duplicate.txt` file:

```
newList = set()

datafile = open ("Duplicate.txt", "r")

for i in datafile:
    if datafile.count(i) >= 2:
        newList.add(i)
datafile.close()

print(list(newList))
```

I'm getting the following error, could anyone help please?

`AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'count'`

Comment: your `datafile` is a handler to the opened file which does not have a method `count`, may you more describe what you want to do or provide the sample file...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is exactly what it says: file objects don't know how to count anything. They're just iterators, not lists or strings or anything like that.

And part of the reason for that is that it would potentially be very slow to scan the whole file over and over like that.

If you really need to use `count`, you can put the lines into a list first. Lists are entirely in-memory, so it's not nearly as slow to scan them over and over, and they have a `count` method that does exactly what you're trying to do with it:

```
datafile = open ("Duplicate.txt", "r")
lines = list(datafile)

for i in lines:
    if lines.count(i) >= 2:
        newList.add(i)

datafile.close()
```

---

However, there's a much better solution: Just keep counts as you go along, and then keep the ones that are >= 2. In fact, you can write that in two lines:

```
counts = collections.Counter(datafile)
newList = {line for line, count in counts.items() if count >= 2}
```

But if it isn't clear to you why that works, you may want to do it more explicitly:

```
counts = collections.Counter()
for i in datafile:
    counts[i] += 1
newList = set()
for line, count in counts.items():
    if count >= 2:
        newList.add(line)
```

Or, if you don't even understand the basics of `Counter`:

```
counts = {}
for i in datafile:
    if i not in counts:
        counts[i] = 1
    else:
        counts[i] += 1
```

Comment: nice & comprehensive answer, but using a counter for this is overkill. You don't want to count, you want to check for more than 1 occurrence. You can do this with 1 aux. set instead of bothering `collections.Counter` bazooka

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, two sets will work, and be more efficient, but I thought it would be more complicated to explain to someone who's thinking in terms of counting. (Although maybe coming up with better names, like `seen` and `repeated`, instead of using the OP's `newList` would help…)

Comment: agreed. Though your solution applies if you want to count elements occurring at least n times.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code is trying to apply `count` on a file handle, not on a `list`.

Anyway, you don't need to count the elements, you just need to see if the element already has been seen in the file.

I'd suggest a marker set to note down which elements already occured.

```
seen = set()
result = set()
with open ("Duplicate.txt", "r") as datafile:
    for i in datafile:
        # you may turn i to a number here with: i = int(i)
        if i in seen:
            result.add(i)  # data is already in seen: duplicate
        else:
            seen.add(i)  # next time it occurs, we'll detect it

print(list(result))  # convert to list (maybe not needed, set is ok to print)
```

Comment: Great answer (I guess it isn't that hard to explain…). But why `sorted` at the end? The OP didn't ask for sorting, and I think it's just going to confuse things given that these lines are supposed to be "numbers" and you're reading and sorting them as strings…

Comment: ;) I guess we all have different ways of over-engineering things. Edited out. We didn't address the "end of line char" which will ruin the display, that said.

Comment: Well, if you really want to overengineer things, you just need to write a key function that handles floats, ints too large to fit in a float, Roman numerals, numbers written out in English, numbers written out in ancient Mongolian, …:)

Comment: err ok let me post such an answer with my second account :)

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate error is because you're asking `if datafile.count(i)` and `datafile` is a file, which doesn't know how to count its contents.

Your question is not about how to solve the larger problem, but since I'm here:
Assuming `Duplicate.txt` contains numbers, one per line, I would probably read each line's contents into a list and then use a Counter to count the list's contents.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use the `list.count()` method, instead you've mistakenly called it on a file object. Instead, lets read the file, split it's contents into a list, and then obtain the count of each item using the `list.count()` method.

```
# read the data from the file
with open ("Duplicate.txt", "r") as datafile:
    datafile_data = datafile.read()

# split the file contents by whitespace and convert to list
datafile_data = datafile_data.split()

# build a dictionary mapping words to their counts
word_to_count = {}
unique_data = set(datafile_data)
for data in unique_data:
    word_to_count[data] = datafile_data.count(data)

# populate our list of duplicates
all_duplicates = []
for x in word_to_count:
    if word_to_count[x] > 2:
        all_duplicates.append(x)
```

Comment: If you `read` the whole file and then `split` it, you're counting words within lines, instead of counting lines like the OP was intending to. Maybe that's what they actually want, or maybe it doesn't matter, but if you're going to make a change like that, you need to explain that you're doing so, and why.

Comment: besides, it's really over complicated and hard to understand.

Comment: Where does the op mention he wanted to count lines? `str.split()` splits the string into a list of words, not a list of lines. So I'm not counting words within lines, I'm counting words within the whole file.